# svcutil and Description attribute

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

When I use SvcUtil to generate the client-side class it does not include the "Description" attribute from the server-side class.

How to do this ?

Comment: you might be able to do something like this with WCFExtras+, which provides a means to extract Documentation attribute from WSDL. http://wcfextrasplus.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll be doing a lot of "heavy lifting" to include documentation in generated client code. SvcUtil does **not** support generating description/documentation from the WSDL.

To accomplish this manually, you need to implement a custom WSDL importer as shown in this [good MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040.aspx) on the subject. Lucky, there is a code sample in the [WCF 4 code samples library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=150780) showing how its done.